# Dropping Mouse Events and Unintentional Drag and Drop

Tags: 12.04, mouse, drag-and-drop

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an Intel I7 system with 9GB RAM and two monitors and I'm using a Logitech wireless mouse (don't have any further information about model).  I have all of the latest updates applied and, with a set of updates applied this week (prior to the most recent kernel update), I began experiencing erratic mouse events (MOUSE_UP not registering / MOUSE_DOWN when not pressed), resulting in repeated  unintentional drag-drop events and text highlighting / dragging affecting all applications.

I've replaced my mouse batteries in an attempt to fix the issue but no joy.  I've rebooted after applying the latest kernel update and still no improvement.

I'm beginning to think this may be a Unity issue.  I'm curious whether anyone else is having this issue and whether there is any known resolution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I should have tried a wired mouse before I posted this - it appears simply to have been wireless interference with my mouse.  The issue is resolved and was *clearly* not Unity.